Tryind to run android emulator from vs (error Failed to install the app)
It does run the emulator but not my app. I can just see the android phone and use it but my app doesn't come
This is the error I get:

error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong: java.io.UncheckedIOException: Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Sony\hello_world\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-47c6c73e-62ac-4055-8d55-2ce7b14ab133) to immutable location (C:\Users\Sony\hello_world\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a) > Could not move temporary workspace (C:\Users\Sony\hello_world\android.gradle\8.6\dependencies-accessors\423f0288fa7dffe069445ffa4b72952b4629a15a-47c6c73e-62ac-4055-8d55-2ce7b14ab133) to immutable location (C:\Users\Sony\hello_world\android.gradle\8.6\tion to get more log output. > Run with --scan to get full insights. > Get more help at https://help.gradle.org. BU�LD FAILED in 8s.
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.

I tried to check `.gradle` but didn't understand much so ..

As mentioned in the error use --verbose flag and check the exact error you are facing, it might be related to permission after seeing this initial error message.
